# CSS not applying to div when adding PHP condition

Tags: php, html, css, if-statement

I want to conditionally display a div so when there are no values, the div is not displayed.
Without the php if part, all is working fine, the css styles are applying to the divs.
But when i add the if condition, the CSS doesn't apply anymore.

Here is the div part:

```
<?php
$getCar_1 = getCar_1();
$getCar_2 = getCar_2();

if(!empty($getCar_1) || !empty($getCar_2)){

?>

<div class="block">
    <div class="up">
        <div class="title"><h4>Cars</h4></div>
    </div>

    <div class="down">
        <div class="column_1"><b><?php getCar_1(); ?></b></div>
        <div class="column_2"><b><?php getCar_2(); ?></b></div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
}
?>
```

and here is the CSS part:

```
.block{
    width:900px;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
}

.up{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    background-color:skyblue;
}

.down{
    width:100%;
    clear:both;
}

.column_1{
    float:left;
    width:47%;
    padding:10px;
}

.column_2{
    float:right;
    width:47%;
    text-align:right;
    padding:10px;
}
```

I know this code is very simple but i can't understand why it is not working properly.

To be more specific. 
If i use only this code:

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="up">
        <div class="title"><h4>Cars</h4></div>
    </div>

    <div class="down">
        <div class="column_1"><b><?php getCar_1(); ?></b></div>
        <div class="column_2"><b><?php getCar_2(); ?></b></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

it display normal:
[using only div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj1RH.jpg)

And when adding the php if part it display this:
[ading php if](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMPUY.jpg)

So when i add the php if, the css has no effect anymore. I also tried the inline styling variant like `<div class="block" style="......">` but it won't work this way either.

EDIT: I'm back because i think the issue comes from the functions get getCar_1(); and getCar_2(); which are in functions.php page and look like this:

```
<?php
function getCar_2(){
global $connect;

$get_car_2 = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE category_id=5";
$get_car_result_2 = mysqli_query($connect, $get_car_2) or die(mysqli_query());

while($row_car_2 = mysqli_fetch_array($get_car_result_2)){
    $car_model_2 = $row_car_2['car_name'];
    $car_image_2 = $row_car_2['car_image'];

    if(isset($car_model_2) && isset($car_image_2)){
        echo "
            <div id='' style='white-space:nowrap;'>
                <p id='model' style='display:inline-block; margin-right:10px; margin-left:10px; padding-top:10px; position:relative; bottom:35px;'>$car_model_2</p></a> 
                <img src='administrator/images/$car_image_2' width='120' height='80' style='display: inline-block; box-shadow: 0 0 11px #000;'/><br>
            </div>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Just to be sure, you mean if you remove PHP if condition from exact code you posted here, it will work ?

Comment: check the values you get with getCar_1() and getCar_2() with an echo for $getCar_1 and $getCar_2

Comment: Yes the css styles apply to divs without the php if condition,

Comment: Does everything work when $getCar_1 or $getCar_2 is not empty? Seems like you are just skipping your entire code so there will be no divs or classes to style.

Comment: 'd like to have a look at `getCar_1()` and `getCar_2()`.

Comment: Also if you want to echo your functions make sure to also define a return value, an inside echo or something like that. Otherwise nothing will be displayed.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem then please mark it as accepted answer to close the thread

Comment: The thing is that the values of getCar_1 and getCar_2 are displayed but the css is not working.

Comment: Could you add some screenshots of what happens?

Comment: I have updated my answer, please try to see if it works.

Comment: I added 2 screenshots up in the original post.

Comment: @AndreiCT I think I have encountered the problem. Please see my updated answer to check if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
if(!empty($getCar_1) || !empty($getCar_2)){

?>
```

Try this:

`if((!empty($getCar_1) || (!empty($getCar_2)): ?>`

and instead of:

`<?php
}
?>`

Try this:
`<?php endif; ?>`

You are not returning anything from `getCar_2()` function. What value you expect to be in `$getCar_2` by line : `$getCar_2 = getCar_2();` same question about `getCar_1()` function if its same like `getCar_2()` with no return statement in it.
Problem is that your `if block` will never execute because your condition:
`if((!empty($getCar_1) || (!empty($getCar_2)):`

will never be true as `$getCar_1` and `$getCar_2` variables will always be empty since `getCar_1()` and `getCar_2()` are not returning anything.

So only `echo` you are providing from the function `getCar_2()` and `getCar_1()` is being printed as output to HTML and your `if` block is not executing at all.

You should put `return` statement in `getCar_2()` and `getCar_1()` functions if you want `if` block to work.Like this:

Instead of:

```
<?php
function getCar_2(){
global $connect;

$get_car_2 = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE category_id=5";
$get_car_result_2 = mysqli_query($connect, $get_car_2) or die(mysqli_query());

while($row_car_2 = mysqli_fetch_array($get_car_result_2)){
    $car_model_2 = $row_car_2['car_name'];
    $car_image_2 = $row_car_2['car_image'];

    if(isset($car_model_2) && isset($car_image_2)){
        echo "
            <div id='' style='white-space:nowrap;'>
                <p id='model' style='display:inline-block; margin-right:10px; margin-left:10px; padding-top:10px; position:relative; bottom:35px;'>$car_model_2</p></a> 
                <img src='administrator/images/$car_image_2' width='120' height='80' style='display: inline-block; box-shadow: 0 0 11px #000;'/><br>
            </div>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Use this:

```
<?php
function getCar_2(){
global $connect;
$response = NULL;
$get_car_2 = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE category_id=5";
$get_car_result_2 = mysqli_query($connect, $get_car_2) or die(mysqli_query());

while($row_car_2 = mysqli_fetch_array($get_car_result_2)){
    $car_model_2 = $row_car_2['car_name'];
    $car_image_2 = $row_car_2['car_image'];

    if(isset($car_model_2) && isset($car_image_2)){
    $response = 'success';
        echo "
            <div id='' style='white-space:nowrap;'>
                <p id='model' style='display:inline-block; margin-right:10px; margin-left:10px; padding-top:10px; position:relative; bottom:35px;'>$car_model_2</p></a> 
                <img src='administrator/images/$car_image_2' width='120' height='80' style='display: inline-block; box-shadow: 0 0 11px #000;'/><br>
            </div>";
        }
    }
return $response;
}
?>
```

*I hope it helps*

Comment: Unfortunately this has no effect, but thanks for the answer.

Comment: If i try with endif, it gives me the followind erorr: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF)

Comment: Did you also do first replacement? Notice `:` after `if()` -> `if((!empty($getCar_1) || (!empty($getCar_2)): ?>`

Comment: Oh sorry i didn't notice from the first time. But now i corrected it and still the same. It does't work. I edit my original post and added 2 pictures, if you want to see what is the problem.

Comment: @AndreiCT I think I have encountered the problem. Please see my updated answer to check if it works.

Comment: Yes, the problem was in the function. I managed to resolved this by similar way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To me seems to be something wrong where you are printing the data, it should be:

```
<?php
$getCar_1 = getCar_1();
$getCar_2 = getCar_2();

if(!empty($getCar_1) || !empty($getCar_2)){

?>

<div class="block">
    <div class="up">
        <div class="title"><h4>Cars</h4></div>
    </div>

    <div class="down">
        <div class="column_1"><b><?php echo $getCar_1; ?></b></div>
        <div class="column_2"><b><?php echo $getCar_2; ?></b></div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: I also tried this variant and it isn't working either.

Comment: Not sure why it isn't working for you but when I try $getCar_1 = 'car1';
$getCar_2 = 'car2'; I get the div but when I do $getCar_1 = '';
$getCar_2 = ''; I don't get the div, so working for me

Comment: For the css part are you using .css file or <style> tags within page?

Comment: I use external file, style.css. I also try the variant in which i copied the stylesheet and pasted it before the respective div and it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The issue was solved with the help of an admin from another forum. As Banzay said it would have been good if i would post the get getCar_1(); and getCar_2(); functions earlier.
The issue was with the functions. Anyway if other beginners like me will have this issue here is the solution.
I modified this:

```
<?php
function getCar_2(){
global $connect;

$get_car_2 = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE category_id=5";
$get_car_result_2 = mysqli_query($connect, $get_car_2) or die(mysqli_query());

while($row_car_2 = mysqli_fetch_array($get_car_result_2)){
    $car_model_2 = $row_car_2['car_name'];
    $car_image_2 = $row_car_2['car_image'];

    if(isset($car_model_2) && isset($car_image_2)){
        echo "
            <div id='' style='white-space:nowrap;'>
                <p id='model' style='display:inline-block; margin-right:10px; margin-left:10px; padding-top:10px; position:relative; bottom:35px;'>$car_model_2</p></a> 
                <img src='administrator/images/$car_image_2' width='120' height='80' style='display: inline-block; box-shadow: 0 0 11px #000;'/><br>
            </div>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

into this:

```
<?php
function getCar_2(){
global $connect;

$text = "";

$get_car_2 = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE category_id=5";
$get_car_result_2 = mysqli_query($connect, $get_car_2) or die(mysqli_query());

while($row_car_2 = mysqli_fetch_array($get_car_result_2)){
    $car_model_2 = $row_car_2['car_name'];
    $car_image_2 = $row_car_2['car_image'];

    if(isset($car_model_2) && isset($car_image_2)){
        $text =  "
            <div id='' style='white-space:nowrap;'>
                <p id='model' style='display:inline-block; margin-right:10px; margin-left:10px; padding-top:10px; position:relative; bottom:35px;'>$car_model_2</p></a> 
                <img src='administrator/images/$car_image_2' width='120' height='80' style='display: inline-block; box-shadow: 0 0 11px #000;'/><br>
            </div>";
        }
    }
    return $text;
}
?>
```

I replaced echo "..." with $text = "..." and returned the variable after the while closing bracket, like this: return $text;
In order to work the $text variable must be initiated before the query like this: $text = "";